# Why is a partial rather than ordinary derivative used here (derivative of point on curve with respect to time)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading some simple differential geometry that had this:
$$
 \int_0^1 \left\| \frac{ \partial f(c(t)) }{\partial t} \right\| dt
= \int_0^1 \left\| \frac{\partial f(c)}{\partial c(t)} \frac{\partial c(t)}{\partial t} \right\| dt
$$
where c(t) is a curve, so in other words integrating a function along a curve in space.

My question: why is $\frac{\partial c(t)}{\partial t}$ a partial rather than ordinary derivative?

My mental definition of partial derivative is: a function of several variables, take the derivative with respect to one with the others held fixed. Here, for the curve $c(t)$, there are no other variables. I think.  For that matter, why does $\frac{ \partial f(c(t)) }{\partial t}$ use the partial derivative?

It makes me think I really do not understand something important and basic, despite being able to possibly parrot the definition.

Comment: This is all totally horrendous notation. You're right that it should be the ordinary derivative of $f(c(t))$ with respect to $t$. What is in the second integral is garbage. I probably shouldn't ask, but where were you reading this?

Comment: At this point I don't remember actually, but it was in a book. I have been studying a number of books and switching between them, and making latex notes. This question struck me when I first read it, but I did not have time to post the question for a while

Comment: TYPO!  I accidentally added an extra $t$ in the second integral, here:
$\frac{\partial c(t)}{\partial t}$.  Hopefully the second integral is not garbage now? (Or if it is, interested to learn why).  Fixing the typo in the main question now.

Comment: It's still garbage, I'm afraid. You should write the chain rule as $$\frac{d}{dt} f(c(t)) = \nabla f(c(t))\cdot c'(t) \quad\text{or}\quad = Df(c(t))(c'(t)).$$ But what is intended is the chain rule. Please do not write a partial derivative with respect to a function $c(t)$. I also find it hard to believe a reasonable published math text would have such a thing in it :( But you're welcome to consult my differential geometry text if that's what you're working on. :) (See my profile.)